# Adding a child to a child

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

In `AS3`, I am trying to add a child to a specific child of a `MovieClip`.

To do this I have done the following:

```
for (var r:Number = 0; r < 2; r++) {
    sand = new Sand();
    sLayers.getChildAt(r).addChild(sand);
}
```

When `sLayers` is the `MovieClip` parent, `r` is the specific child of `sLayers`, and `sand` is the child I want to add.

It comes up with the following error:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild 
      through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Sorry I simplified the code, it would take up too much space.

Is there another way to do this? Or am I close but just missing something?

Comment: The error is because `getChildAt()` returns a display object (which may or may not be a displayObjectContainer that can have children of it's own.   You need to cast as `DisplayObjectContainer` or `Sprite` to not get the compiler error.   If any child of `sLayers` is not a descendant of `DisplayObjectContainer`, (like `Shape` or `Bitmap` for instance) you will not be able to add a child to it.

Comment: eg:  `if(sLayers.getChildAt(r) is Sprite) Sprite(sLayers.getChildAt(r)).addChild(sand);` where the cast **Sprite(object)** is telling the compiler that the object is actually a Sprite (or a sub class of it like MovieClip)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
for(var r:Number = 0; r < 2; r++)
{
    var sand:Sand = new Sand;
    (sLayers.getChildAt(r) as MovieClip).addChild(sand);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer to make it more useful.    You make the assumption that all the children of `sLayers` are MovieClips, your answer will not hold up if there are `Shape`, `Sprite` or `Bitmap` instances as children.    I would suggest modifying your code to include a check for `is DisplayObjectContainer` before doing a cast and addChild.  Also, you're missing the instantiation brackets on `new Sand()`;